# Predict a company business classification

Tags: machine-learning, index, prediction, nlp

I am trying to predict whether companies belong to a universe considered by an index provider for a particular thematic index using natural language processing techniques.

In this particular example, I am looking at a universe of c. 5000 chinese stocks.
I want to predict whether those stocks may fit the sector classification of a thematic index of "internet" stocks.
The description from the provider for this index reads as follows:

[image]

The provider here does not use standard classification such as, for example GICS.
However, I have at my disposal for each stock some text that describes the parent company's business.

Ideally, based on this text, I want to be able to produce a probability indicating the likelihood of matching the provider classification.
I have a history of the index composition so I know what stocks in the past have belonged to that index.

I am not a nlp expert but I am interested in any ideas, from the simplest (maybe just a word frequency count) to more complex ones using maybe word/sentence embeddings?

Comment: These may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555021/supervised-latent-dirichlet-allocation-for-document-classification https://github.com/Sivalavida/Text-based-Industry-Classification https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/text-classification-using-lda-35d5b98d4f05 https://towardsdatascience.com/latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda-9d1cd064ffa2 .